# php - using session in program

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram messenger allow programer to build your own Bot. 
my bot have a keyboard. users can select every key and bot show proper response.
in my example, when user press "mobile" or "/mobile", bot reply is new keyboard: "sony", "Nokia", "Lg". and by pressing nokia, bot show proper response
also user can type "Nokia" directly and robot reply to it

my problem is:
is any why to force users to select nokia, "only" after press mobile?
the other word, when user type nokia directly, bot show him: "you need to select mobile first"

```
$data       = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$client     = new Zelenin\Telegram\Bot\Api($token);

$chatid     = $data['message']['chat']['id'];
$text       = $data['message']['text'];
$messageid  = $data['message']['message_id'];


if($text == "/mobile" || "mobile"){ 
        $params     = array('chat_id' => $chatid, 'action' => 'typing');
        $response   = $client -> sendChatAction($params);
                //keyboard
        $keyboard = array("sony \xF0\x9F\x93\x9E","nokia \xF0\x9F\x8E\xA5","LG \xF0\x9F\x92\xB0");
        $start_keys = array('keyboard'=>array($keyboard));
        $encodedMarkup = json_encode($start_keys);
        $message = " \xF0\x9F\x93\x8C please press correct key ...";
        $content = array('chat_id' => $chatid,'reply_markup' => $encodedMarkup,'text' => $message);
        $response   = $client -> sendMessage($content);
        $response   = $client -> forwardMessage(array('chat_id' => $agroup, 
                'message_id' => $messageid, 'from_chat_id' => $chatid));
} else {
        $params     = array('chat_id' => $chatid, 'action' => 'typing');
        $response   = $client -> sendChatAction($params);
        $message = " \xF0\x9F\x93\x8C please press ...";    
        $response   = $client -> sendMessage($content);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a field called menu to users table with the default set to SelectMobile. 
When the user press other than mobile, check the field, if it was SelectMobile, ask him to do so. When the user press mobile, update that field to SelectBrand. Again if user sends other than brands, tell him he needs to send a specified brand.